# smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful+django

Tags: django, azure, email, smtp, office365

Im trying to configure SMTP for my DJANGO application and im getting this error

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully.
```

The username and password are correct and also the two factor authentication is not enabled. Below are email settings added to the application.

```
EMAIL_HOST="smtp.office365.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER="no-reply@domain.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="***********"
EMAIL_USE_TLS="True"
EMAIL_PORT="587"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL="EMAIL_HOST_USER"
```

The MX record is

```
domain.mail.protection.outlook.com.
```

What am i missed!? Kindly guide me through.

I found microsoft has stopped the use of basic auth for Exchange online and should i configure OAuth?
If yes please give me any documentation that i can reffer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can enable SMTP authentication for a user in the Microsoft Admin center. This is disabled by default.

Comment: hi Alexander, 
The SMTP authentication for this user is enabled and yet i'm receiving the same error.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? @VishnuNandananMK I am having the same problem